# Linq query on datatable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable, dataset

I have 2 datasets ds1 and ds2 ds1 contains valid values used in ds2 for e.g. ds1 contains subject table containing Maths, Science, History. ds2 contains Student table Student table contains Subject column. ds2->Student->Subject values should be present in ds->subject table.

How to implement this type of validation in effective way. I don't want to iterate through each row and column of student table.

e.g.
Students Table
Name      Subject        Status
Peter       Maths          Fail
George    Science        Pass
Joe           IT                Pass
Roger     History          Other

Subjects Table
Subject
Maths
Science
Maths
History

Status Table
Status 
Pass 
Fail

Now I want to validate the data in Students Table against Subject table Check if the Subject is present in Subjects table or not. Here I want row Joe IT since IT is not present in Subjects table it is invalid.

Similarly , I need to check Students table data with Status table.

Expected Output

Subject         IT               
Status      Other

I want LINQ query.

Comment: Currently I am using DataTable to query.

Comment: What do you have so far in a LINQ query, what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
var noSubject =
  ds.Student.AsEnumerable().Where(s => ds.Subject.Rows.Find(s.Subject) == null);
```

Assuming Subject is PK in the Subject ds.